# Download whole folder from Dropbox Android sdk

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am integrating dropbox in my Android sdk to download all files from dropbox,
I am able to downloadin all files from each folder but now I need to download whole folder from the specific path from dropbox.

I have tried with

```
    DropboxFileInfo info = mApi.getFile(path + FileName,null, out, null);
```

One of the app already in the Google play store that is specaily to download dropbox files and folder [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jjinx.dropboxdownloader)

I have referred 
[this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android)

but not able to download whole folder 
Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official Dropbox api guide [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android)

```
private boolean downloadDropboxFile(String dbPath, File localFile) throws IOException{

BufferedInputStream br = null;
BufferedOutputStream bw = null;

try {
    if (!localFile.exists()) {
        localFile.createNewFile(); //otherwise dropbox client will fail silently
    }

    FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox", dbPath, null);
    br = new BufferedInputStream(fd.is);
    bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int read;
    while (true) {
    read = br.read(buffer);
    if (read <= 0) {
    break;
    }
    bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
} finally {
    //in finally block:
    if (bw != null) {
        bw.close();
    }
    if (br != null) {
        br.close();
    }
}

return true;
```

}

Here is the source : https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=23189&replies=5#post-159521

Comment: What is FileDownload in " FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox", dbPath, null);"

Comment: fd is the variable to store the file that is being downloaded.

Comment: I am not able to use  FileDownload , can you please tell me How can I use? I am using Dropbox sdk jar

Comment: Have you followed the step by step process in https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android#downloading

Comment: Yes I have follow that , But How can get File Download class ?

Comment: Unless i should get your files or desktopshare to help you

Comment: can we have on chat for this problem ?